# WooCommerce cant use meta_query for filter product with price range

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filter, hook-woocommerce, price

please help me. I cant use meta_query to filter products with a price range

```
if ( ! empty( $data['price_range'] ) ) {
        
        $price_range = explode( '|', esc_attr($data['price_range']) );

        if ( is_array($price_range) && count($price_range) == 2 ) {

            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => '_price',
                'value' => array(reset($price_range), end($price_range)),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            );
        }

    }
    
    $products = wc_get_products( $args );
```

and this for final "$args" value

```
[meta_query] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [key] => _price
                [value] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 6.28
                        [1] => 6.56
                    )

                [compare] => BETWEEN
                [type] => NUMERIC
            )

    )
```

other "$args" value is [post_status] => publish
[post_type] => Array
(
[0] => product
[1] => product_variation
)

thanks for your help before

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', 'handle_price_range_query_var', 10, 2);

function handle_price_range_query_var($query, $query_vars) {
    if (!empty($query_vars['price_range'])) {
        $price_range = esc_attr($query_vars['price_range']);

        if (is_array($price_range) && count($price_range) == 2) {

            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => '_price',
                'value' => array(reset($price_range), end($price_range)),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            );

            $query['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num'; // sort by price
            $query['order'] = 'ASC'; // In ascending order
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Add the above code in your active theme fucntions.php and use the function below to get ([custom filter](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query#adding-custom-parameter-support)) the products between the price range.

```
$args['price_range'] = array(6.8,6.56);
$products = wc_get_products($args);
```

Tested OK with **WooCommerce 6.4**

Answer (score 0):

I believe to use meta_query with wc_get_products you have to follow the “adding custom parameter support” section at the bottom of this page [wc_get_products](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query)

It is not otherwise supported. So you would otherwise need to use get_posts

Comment: can you give me some code example for get products data using get_posts?

Comment: @RobyAp As @jtowell mentioned, there is no meta_query default support for `wc_get_products()` - only support for internal meta keys. ie - internal_meta_keys(Data stored in meta keys, but not considered "meta" for an object)